# print variable names in my own function r

Tags: r, printf, cat

I want to create a funtion that creates new data frames using some variables from other data frames. For that I thing I need to print the variable names in my own function somehow.

The variables come from two data frames (asd and tetracam) which have six variables in common, the bands "w530", "w550", "w570", "670", "w700" and "w800". So, I want to create six data frames, one for each band. One by one I could write like this:

```
# Band w530
w530<-data.frame(tetracam$filename,tetracam$time,tetracam$type,tetracam$w530,asd$w530)
names(w530)<-c("filename","time","type","tetracam","asd")
w530<-w530[order(w530$time),]
```

It works fine but I'd like to do it as a function in order to run for all bands. I thought I have to replace all the w530 in the code above for a dinamic object. As I thought of using some of the apply family. So, I first created a list with the names of my common variables:

```
bands<-c("w530","w550","w570","670","w700","w800")
```

Then, I tried several ways, for example, using `cat` or `sprintf` that would use the strings from the list to fill my function. But it didn't work. Actually, I'm not sure which `apply` family function I would use. If it's possible to use any in this case:

```
my.fun<- function(band){
  sprintf("%s<-data.frame(tetracam$filename,tetracam$time,tetracam$type,asd$%s,tetracam$%s)",band,band,band)
  sprintf("names(%s)<-c('filename','time','type','asd','tetracam')",band)
  sprintf("%s[order(%s$time),]",band,band)
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You are not passing those two data frames, i.e. asd and tetracam, into the function. Try to add two more argument two the function and use these two as your input. Otherwise, function cannot access to the environment variables by default.

Comment: Please use `dput` to provide a reproducible example of your data-set.

Comment: [Why accept an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). Accepting an answer helps other people with the same question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trick is to access data.frame column using `df[varName]` idiom.

```
fun1 <- function(band, tetracam, asd){

  df<-data.frame(tetracam$filename,tetracam$time,tetracam$type,tetracam[band],asd[band])
  names(df)<-c("filename","time","type","tetracam","asd")
  df<-df[order(df$time),]
  return(df)
}

for (band in bands){
  single_band_df <- fun1(band, tetracam, asd)
}
```

Comment: @ Vince Thanks a lot. Simple like that and did exactly what I needed.